# How am I using Xcode Search incorrectly?

Tags: xcode

Xcode search just isn't working the way I expect it to.  What am I doing wrong?

1. "Project Find" (cmd-shift-F) often turns up zero results when I KNOW that there are valid hits.  For example, searching for "Search Results" (no quotes) ironically returns 0 hits, even though I have a .m project file open with the string @"Search Results" sitting right in front of me.  My Find Options are set as loosely as i can make then, case-insensitive, Search In Open Projects, All Candidate Files, All Files in this Project, etc.
2. The Search bar in the upper right of my main project window doesn't seem to behave like Project Find, nor does it seem to search the currently open document.  What does it do?
3. Searching for "UIView" in the Help menu search turns up zero hits, even though if I open up the Developer Documentation from the Help menu and search from that window it returns plenty of hits.

Comment: Could you add a screen shot of your Find Options for search type 1? That should be working.  Search type 2 is for filtering file names in the Detail view, not searching file contents, and search style 3 is for searching Xcode menu items and Help content, not project source or developer documentation.

Comment: Great idea, but i think i figured it out.  The problem was that I was searching by Symbol rather than by text.  Whoops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Help menu searches only for menu entries (try searching for "Paste") and end-user documentation (how to use the software itself, not how to develop it).

Use documentation viewer to search within developer documentation (it lets you switch between fulltext and API names search, select OS version and language).

Check what options you've set in project search – it might be set to match whole identifiers only, be case-sensitive, search only selected files, etc.

Select:

- In Project
- Textual
- Contains
- Ignore case

Uncheck:

- <s>Display Resutlts in Find Smart Group</s>

Answer (score 1):

This might help :

1. If you are searching files in project then select "Ignoring case". Below is screenshot for the same.

[image: Condition 1]

2. If you are searching a particular file then select magnifier -> Edit finding option.. -> Select/Unselect Matching case accordingly. Below is screenshot for the same.

[image: Condition 2 - a]

[image: Condition 2 - b]

Answer (score 0):

In my case the Pods project had an issue and Xcode could open it. Thus, although the files were there, Xcode could search through them.